# Ajax event calendar php shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Shorcode for adding Ajax Event calender in php pages.
we have a [calendar] Shortcode .But it can't add it any php page.
Hope You help

Answer (score 1):

The plugin's FAQ answers this question.

https://code.google.com/p/wp-aec/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_can_I_include_the_calendar_directly_in_my_theme_without_usin